# wordpress run php file in form action

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to re-do my site to wordpress, I have this problem. I have a form and on a submit php file runs and adds data to database. How do I run php file in wordpress?

```html
<form method="POST" action="insert.php"> 
<p>
     <label for="XX">XX</label>
     <input type="text" name="XX" id="XX">
      
      <label for="X">X</label>
     <input type="text" name="X" id="X">
      <label for="XXY">XXY</label>
     <input type="text" name="XXY" id="XXY">
      
</p>
    <input type="submit" value="add to database">
</form>
```

How do I run the php insert.php file? Thank you!

Or on the other hand, could I write in action the directory to the file? eg. wp-content/myphpfiles/insertgolf.php, would that work? Thank you, I am new to wordpress

Comment: this form in temaplte or admin page content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WordPress form page, you can not put php file path. If you want to do this then you need to create a template.

Please follow reference link, here you can know how to create template in WordPress: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/creating-custom-page-template-in-wordpress/

In template file put your code:

```
<?php /* Template Name: insertGolf */ 
    if(!empty($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    //do database related code here

       $link = mysqli_connect("c108um.DDD.com","f96860","qt3C2EQ","f96860"); 
if($link === false){
   die("ERROR: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 } 
 $datum = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['datum']); 
 $odkud = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['odkud']); 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO golf (datum, odkud) VALUES ('$datum', '$odkud')";
 if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){ header('Location: golf.php');
 exit;
 }
 else{ 
 echo "ERROR: " . mysqli_error($link);
 } 
 mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
<form method="POST" action=""> 
<p>
        <label for="XX">XX</label>
        <input type="text" name="XX" id="XX">

      <label for="X">X</label>
        <input type="text" name="X" id="X">
      <label for="XXY">XXY</label>
        <input type="text" name="XXY" id="XXY">      
</p>
    <input type="submit" value="add to database">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it should work. What should I write in the <Form action="?"> ? I made a new page called myphp and that works, but I am unable to redirect form to that new page

Comment: when you create a template and then create a page, include that template on this page. Now left action="" blank. when you submit the form.

Comment: I hope it will make sense.

Comment: Ok, so I have created a new page that runs on myphp template and put the form in it (action=""). That doesnt work right, it proceeds to run the myphp before I put a values in the form and get my error message "No values to submit"

Comment: put your form code into the template and handle the request in that template.

Comment: <?php /* Template Name: insertGolf */ ?>

<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("c108um.DDD.com","f96860","qt3C2EQ","f96860");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
$datum = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['datum']);
$odkud = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['odkud']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO golf (datum, odkud) VALUES ('$datum', '$odkud')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
header('Location: golf.php');
exit;
} else{
    echo "ERROR:  " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>

Comment: It is a simple put in database. I could put the form and the insertphp on one page, how do I do that?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that works. One last little problem. How do I redirect (or do not redirect user when form is submitted to the same page?
header('Location: ??');

Comment: you can use header('Location: http://www.nameofnewsite.com');
exit();
 or

Comment: wp_redirect( $url );
exit;